# React native viro, framework not found ViroKit_static_lib error when building on ios

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, augmented-reality

I'm currently developing a Ar app with react native app ( version 0.55.2) and viro (version 12).
I followed their tutorial to install Viro on ios and Android. (https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/integrating-with-react-native-projects).
It's working great on Android but I have build error on xcode.
I followed these steps to install viro on ios (https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/no_use_frameworks). 
My podfile looks as follow

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.3'

    target 'treasureHunters' do
      # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks

      # Pods for project
      pod 'ViroReact', :path => '../node_modules/react-viro/ios/'
      pod 'ViroKit_static_lib', :path => '../node_modules/react-viro/ios/dist/ViroRenderer/static_lib'  

    end
```

I had pod install success message. the pod lock look like this

```
PODS:
  - ViroKit_static_lib (1.0)
  - ViroReact (1.0)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - ViroKit_static_lib (from `../node_modules/react-viro/ios/dist/ViroRenderer/static_lib`)
  - ViroReact (from `../node_modules/react-viro/ios/`)

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  ViroKit_static_lib:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-viro/ios/dist/ViroRenderer/static_lib"
  ViroReact:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-viro/ios/"

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  ViroKit_static_lib: 17cb5bbb409057a98d2922cef37afb6b132dd630
  ViroReact: 5520f26ac4654e361786c82da3b29ce0402c3c00

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 4df8dc354119fe43ff9c12440dce232d09df282d

COCOAPODS: 1.5.2
```

I opened the xcworkspace file, I set the Enable Bitcode at no. When I build the project I have a error from  linker-command failed with exit code 1 with this message : " framework not found ViroKit_static_lib".

I'm not sure how to tackle this. Is there a path to change somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In your project's Build Settings, add this to **Framework Search Paths**:

`"${PODS_ROOT}/../../node_modules/react-viro/ios/dist/ViroRenderer/static_lib"`

Add this to **Library Search Paths**:

`"${PODS_ROOT}/../../node_modules/react-viro/ios/dist/lib"`

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. I added both path as recursive but It still have the error.

Comment: when I look into the pods release xcconfig, the paths are LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/../../node_modules/react-viro/ios/dist/lib" and FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/../../node_modules/react-viro/ios/dist/ViroRenderer/static_lib". Do I need to remove the ${inherited} ?

Comment: @kwertkt No you should not remove it, I have it in my config as well. 
Check the `Other Linker Flags` and make sure `$(inherited)` is added there.

Comment: I added  ${inherited} to project other linker flags. Still same error. should I add it somewhere else?

Comment: That's strange. Your config seems to be ok.. I created a new project and followed viro's guide and it worked with no issues.

Comment: it could be related to the fact that I also had mapbox, notifications and bunch of other dependencies. I 'm gonna dig more. Thank you very much, you've been very helpful